# Handle json array CAKEPHP

Tags: json, cakephp

Here's my javascript snipet

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('form#FormId button.btn').click(function(event){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/controller/edit",
                data: $("#FormId").serialize(), 
                success: function(response) {
                    alert(response.message);
                    alert(response['message']);
                }
            }); 
        });
    });
```

Here's my controller action

```
public function edit() {
    $this->autoRender = false; // We don't render a view in this example
    $this->request->onlyAllow('ajax'); // No direct access via browser URL

    echo json_encode(array('message'=>'Welcome','type'=>'success'));

    exit;
}
```

Both alerts on the javascript are returning "undefined" how to handle?

Comment: Don't you need  dataType: 'json' in your $.ajax statement?

Comment: In general, using json_encode() and/or exit() directly is not the best practice. Since 2.x the view layer (View class) should be responsible for that. See http://www.dereuromark.de/2014/01/09/ajax-and-cakephp/ for details.

Answer (score 1):

So nobody is getting this correct.

You need to use the [JSON view](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html)

See how to enable with [this section](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html#enabling-data-views-in-your-application)

```
class PostsController extends AppController {
    public $components = array('RequestHandler');

    public function index() {
        $this->request->onlyAllow('ajax');
        $this->set(array(
            'data' => array('message'=>'Welcome','type'=>'success'),
            '_serialize' => 'data',
        ));
    }
}
```

Cake will now automatically set the correct headers, serialize as JSON and not render the layout.

As a side note, your code `alert(response.message);` does not work beacuse `response` is a string. your header is `text/html` not `application/json`. Try `console.log(response)` and you will see it is just a string.

Comment: Don't know why, i cannot manage to get a response using this method, i've the RequestHandler enabled on the AppController, and the Router::parseExtensions('json','xml'); on routes.php when using this method the response is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I get this to work using the following code in the controller

```
public function edit()
{
    $this->RequestHandler->respondAs('json'); // Very important without this it will not work
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $data = array('message'=>'Welcome','type'=>'success');
    return json_encode($data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try add

```
 dataType: 'json',
```

to your ajax method.

if it not work, try this:
add

```
$this->response->type('text/plain');
```

to your index method.

ie brower did not know json format text. 
and what broswer did you used for this test?  use F12 open the developer kit to check what the server response, is it a objct

Answer (score -1):

From my experience echoing content doesn't work. You should instead return the json_encoded data.

This will make your `edit()` function look like this:

```
public function edit()
{
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $this->request->onlyAllow('ajax');

    return json_encode(array('message' => 'Welcome', 'type' => 'success'));
}
```

To make sure it works; just alert the whole response object to see what is returned.

Comment: Alert the response only get [object Object]. Better to use console.log(response);

Comment: Here's the alert from response: {"message":"Welcome","type":"success"}

Comment: If you now type in: `console.log(response.message) or alert(response.message)`, you should see "Welcome"